# tar exclude certain directories but not in subdirectories

Tags: gnu-tar

I need to transfer a lot of web directories to another machine. The directory structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/
    site1/
        cgi-bin/ ...
        logs/ ...
        index.html
        images/ ...
        ...
    site2/
        cgi-bin/
        logs/
        ...
    size3/
    ...
```

To pack the files I'd like to use `tar`. I need to pack all files, except all "cgi-bin" and all "logs" directories **only** in certain provided paths, not in any subdirectory!

These directories should be excluded from packing because they should not appear in the destination and they can be quite large. That slows down the transfer. So I *do not* want to include them and only delete them in the destination.

I tried several combinations of this:

```
cd /var/www
tar cfz ~/web.tgz site* --exclude-from excludes.list
```

excludes.list is a file that contains lines such as shown here: (the example shows different path styles, I used each of them consistently for the entire file, but no variant worked)

```
site1/cgi-bin
site1/logs
./site2/cgi-bin
/var/www/site2/logs
```

The "cgi-bin" directories may occur in other subdirectories (I list them all with a `find` command), the "logs" directories that I want to exclude are all directly in each "site*x*" directory. Other "logs" directories **must be included**.

I could only get to two results:

1. No files were excluded at all
2. All directories that *partially* matched an exclude pattern were excluded, including e.g. /var/www/site2/bla/site1/logs/. This is not acceptable as it's **excluding too much**.

Is there a way to make `tar` exclude exactly the absolute paths provided and nothing else that partially looks like a provided exclude pattern?

Comment: Is it feasible to you to build `excludes.list` file all contains relative or all absolute paths?

Comment: I did that, as I explained. All paths were consistent, these are just different examples.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a process substitution and `find` to build the list of directories you want to exclude.
I'm assuming your `find` implementation supports the `-maxdepth` option:

```
cd /var/www
tar cfz ~/web.tgz --exclude-from=<(
  find site* -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'logs'
  find site* -type d -name 'cgi-bin'
) site*
```

---

Test setup:

```
site1/
├── cgi-bin
│   └── file1
├── images
│   ├── cgi-bin
│   │   └── file2
│   └── logs
│       └── file3
├── index.html
└── logs
    └── file4
```

Output:

```
$ tar cvfz ~/web.tgz --exclude-from=<(
  find site* -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'logs'
  find site* -type d -name 'cgi-bin'
) site*
site1/
site1/images/
site1/images/logs/
site1/images/logs/file3
site1/index.html
```

Excluded directories (output of both `find` commands):

```
site1/logs
site1/cgi-bin
site1/images/cgi-bin
```

Comment: That's about what I already did, just using a separate file instead of piping the find result directly into the tar process. What are the lines your find produces? Are they different to mine? (I showed them above.) If not, this is not an answer but still my question.

Comment: Added output of my test setup, I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: `--exclude-from` is a nonportable GNU tar extension. Other tar implementations use a different option name for this feature. Modern tar implementations use `libfind` and thus support to use a `find(1)` like command line directly. See e.g. http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html

Comment: @schily It is clear that this question is specifically about GNU `tar`, and that the answer addresses GNU `tar`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Why didn't you change the tag from `tar` to `gnu-tar` if you believe this is obvious to all readers?

Comment: @schily Done. Thanks for the suggestion.